# Cannot remove gradient

Tags: css

I'm trying to remove gradient overriding this:

```
  -webkit-linear-gradient(right,#1a5cce, #00c7ce 85%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,#1a5cce, #00c7ce 85%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(right,#1a5cce, #00c7ce 85%);
background: linear-gradient(right,#1a5cce, #00c7ce 85%);
```

I tried with:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(none);
                    background: -moz-linear-gradient(none);
                    background: -o-linear-gradient(none);
                    background: linear-gradient(none);
```

I'm not a css expert, what I want to do is remove completely the gradient, is this possible?

Comment: Use `background: none`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `background: initial`.
All CSS properties allow `initial` value to revert their value to initial state. Use this property what you don't want to bother about particular property defaults.

Also you can use `background: none` for `background` property.

Comment: in my case doesn't seems working, I've the default gradient in style.css, and I've another file that add dynamic css, in this file I need to remove the gradient setted from style.css but both none e initial doesn't work for me (also putting !important), any ideas? thanks

Comment: @AalokAmalmani This must work with `!important`. Something wrong with your files or another `!important` applied. Please use browser developer tools to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: It could also be a specificity issue.

Comment: Also, the second file should be loaded after your initial `style.css`

Answer (score 0):

Gradient background reset that you'll need to set

```
background: none #color;
```

Example:

```
.your-class {

  background: none #157FCC;
  color: #FFFFFF;

}
```